# Dart private variable returns null in other functions

Tags: dart, private-members

I have declared a private variable in dart `_finalScore` which is later assigned a value or result `_finalScore = prevRes + currResult`. It works well where i set the value to it but after that in another function when i try to you the private variable in another function `if(_finalScore > 25) return "Good Performace"` in same class, it(_finalScore) return null.

```
  CalculatorScore({this.prevScore, this.currScore});

  final int prevScore;
  final int currScore;

  double _finalScore;

  String calculateScore() {
    double _finalScore= prevScore + currScore;
    return _finalScore.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getScoreRemark() {
    if (_finalScore >= 60) {
      return "Good work";
    } else if (_finalScore > 50) {
      return "Work hard";
    } else {
      return "Poor performace";
    }
  }
}
```

```
calculateScore() works well with _finalScore receiving a value but _finalScore returns null in getScoreRemark()
```

Any help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are not setting the value of the class variable `_finalScore` but instead creating a new local variable inside the `calculateScore` method:

```
String calculateScore() {
    double _finalScore = ...
    return ...
}
```

you should remove the type and assign the value to the variable

```
_finalScore = ...
```